# Proving i-th Fibonacci number by induction, can an inductive step be used for two sequential values?

Tags: proof-verification, induction, fibonacci-numbers

I am working through the beginning of Introduction to Algorithms, and came across the problem

> Prove by induction that the $i$-th Fibonacci number satisfies the equality 
>   $$ F_{i} = \frac{\phi^{i} - \hat{\phi^{i}}}{\sqrt{5}}$$
>   where $\phi$ and $\hat{\phi}$ are the golden ratio and it's conjugate, respectively.

Now I know there are *plenty* of answers online regarding this proof, and I have already come to understand a few ways to approach it, but I am simply curious about the approach I originally took to solving the problem and whether it is valid or not.

**I am fairly convinced it is invalid**, but I want to double check and wonder if there is some mechanism in the proof I can change to validate it.

---

#### My approach:

First, I proved (*trivially*) that both $\phi$ and $\hat{\phi}$ satisfy the equation 
\begin{equation}
x^{2} = x+1 \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Then after trivially proving the base cases for the inductive proof, for the inductive step we assume 
$$ F_{k} = \frac{\phi^{k} - \hat{\phi^{k}}}{\sqrt{5}}$$
for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$.

Then for $k+1$, we have 
\begin{align}
\frac{\phi^{k+1} - \hat{\phi^{k+1}}}{\sqrt{5}} &= \frac{\phi^{k-1}\phi^{2} - \hat{\phi}^{k-1}\hat{\phi^{2}}}{\sqrt{5} } \\
&= \frac{\phi^{k-1}(\phi + 1) - \hat{\phi}^{k-1}(\hat{\phi} + 1)}{\sqrt{5}} && \text{by (1)} \\
&= \frac{\phi^{k} - \hat{\phi}^{k}}{\sqrt{5}} + \frac{\phi^{k-1} - \hat{\phi}^{k-1}}{\sqrt{5}} \\
&= F_{k} + F_{k-1} \\
&= F_{k+1} && \text{by definition}
\end{align}

This looks downright incorrect to me because it implies that the inductive step holds for $k-1$, which is not permitted in inductive proofs, correct? If so, are there any measures I can take to validate this proof? I've already worked out a solution going the other way with the recurrence relation, I'm just curious how close this might be (I haven't touched inductive proofs in a while)

Comment: Induction is a matter of assuming something is true for k.  *what* is true for k can be anything you want.  Weak induction is where you assume "prop is true for n = k".  **Strong** induction is where you assume "prop is true for $n \le k$"  Either assumption is perfectly valid *if* you can show that your assumption implies "prop is true for n = k + 1".  So **yes** that is *utterly* acceptable.

Comment: @fleablood Now I feel ridiculous for asking, but thanks a ton.

Comment: one thing you have to watch out for with strong induction is that as your only base case was $n = 1$ you can not assume if true for $n \le k$ you may *NOT* assume $k > 1$.  If you refer to a k -1 case you must show a *two* base cases.  Either n = 0 and n = 1 or n =1 and n = 2.

Comment: So you **do** have a small problem.  For $k = 1$ you haven't shown that that F_0 is defined.  So you must do a base base case of F_0 = 0 and property holds.  Which can be a definition

Comment: @fleablood Yes yes my apologies, I should have been more clear in that respect, I proved the base cases for $F_{0}$ and $F_{1}$, showing their definition. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $k\ge 1$, let $A_k$ be the assertion that $F_k$ and $F_{k-1}$ **both** satisfy the condition.

You have shown that if $A_k$ holds, then the condition is satisfied at $k+1$, and therefore that $A_{k+1}$ holds. So you have proved that $A_n$ holds for all $n$, and therefore that $F_n$ satisfies the condition for all $n$.

For another approach that is more generally useful, please see *strong induction* aka *complete induction*.